# c++ globals initialization order (not fiasco)

Tags: c++, templates, g++

Consider the following snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename T, int I>
T singleton;

struct A{
    int x = 100;
    A(){
        printf("A ctor: x = %d\n", x);
    }
};

template<int I>
A& getA(){
    A&ret= singleton<A, I>;
    printf("get A: x = %d \n", ret.x);
    return ret;
}

A& a = getA<0>();

int main(){

}
```

In gcc the output is:

```
get A: x = 0 
A ctor: x = 100
```

In clang the order is the one I'd expect:

```
A ctor: x = 100
get A: x = 100
```

Is this an issue with gcc?

Please note that this is NOT the dreaded static initialization order fiasco, as it's happening within a single compilation unit.

Code can be found here https://godbolt.org/z/8zaP4z1e9

Comment: Isn't this just https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start#dynamic-1 ?

Comment: @dyp not sure what you mean. In this case I don't see specializations

Comment: A specialization is (surprisingly) a general term which also covers implicit instantiations: https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec.general#4